# How do I acquire Precision Tools

Tags: dwarf-fortress

This is in the LFR mod, and it is needed to make pretty much make all of the higher tier buildings. None of the buildings that I am able to build have it as an option, I have gone through the manual and it makes it seem like I have to "acquire" them in some fashion. What is the deal?

Comment: @Ullallulloo this is no tag for the masterwork mod so I don't think there should be a tag for LFG mod.

Comment: I checked that first, but we don't have any questions specific to Masterwork.

Comment: @Ullallulloo I have seen a few.

Comment: @Ullallulloo I do!

Answer (score 1):

The manual for LFR can be confusing, but per **lfr_mechanical_tech_tree.txt**, section **[2.4] Orichalcum**, you can use orichalcum at an alchemy lab to get precision tools. See the quoted section below (emphasis mine).

> The way to advance to the next tier of the mechanical tech tree, you'll need to get your hands on some precision tools.  In all but the rarest of cases, this means you're going to be after some **orichalcum** - a rare metal that occurs primarily in microcline and orthoclase deposits.  Do whatever you have to do to get ahold of this material - **you only need a single bar in order to fashion the first set of precision tools at the alchemy lab**.  Either dig around (explore the caverns) or trade for some orichalcum with the dwarven caravan.  Once you have a bar of the stuff, it can be fashioned into a precision tool kit at the alchemy lab (no fuel is required).